# MVC paging without using Entity Framework in View Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, view, paging

I have a scenario in my MVC application where I am displaying a data table retrieved in the view page using html table tags. I am able to add search functionality without any issue, but I am having issue with adding paging. I am considering using IPagerList option, but I am not using entity class here to store the values, as I cannot have direct binding in code with db. Is it possible to apply paging in my code without using the entity framework with databinding ?

The model in the below code is a datatable contained within an dataset.

**Actual view Code:**

```
 <% foreach(System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows) { %>
                    <tr>
                        <% foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray) {%>
                            <td><%=cell.ToString() %></td>
                        <%} %>
                    </tr>
 <%} %>
```

Comment: `IPagerList` isn't bound to Entity Framework at all, just use it.

Comment: I assume you mean `IPagedList`? And I assume you're getting data as a LINQ-to-Entities query that you transform to a DataTable? It's not entirely clear at which point in the data transfer PagedList should be applied. And why do you use a DataTable in the first place?

Comment: No Gert the approach I am using here is straight forward, I am using the model class as data access layer method, using a stored procedure to retrieve the details from db and display in datatable. But for binding with PagedList I am required to use Entity class, instead of that can i use the table with dataset (ds.tables[0]).